# How can I Automatically generate sql insert scripts when data is available in some specific template in microsoft excel?

Tags: sql, excel

How can I Automatically generate sql insert scripts when data is available in some specific template in microsoft excel?Say for example i have four columns in the excel file as table_name and the others as column_1,column_2 and column_3 and their respective values. Now based on the values present in these columns the insert scripts has to be generated, like insert into table_name (column_1,column_2,column_3) values('v1','v2','v3'); . Suggest me the best way by which i can do this? Instead of microsoft excel other options are also fine.

Answer (score 1):

**For Excel to create insert statements:**

```
"INSERT INTO table_name VALUES('"&A1&"','"&B1&"','"&C1&"')"
```

or

```
"insert into  product (product_id,name,date,price) values("&A1&",'" &B1& "','" &C1& "'," &D1& ");"
```

Comment: the column name and table name are not always same and it is going to vary

Comment: are the table name and the column names always in the same columns/cells?

if you don't wanna create the statements with a statement like above, you could also create i.e. a powershell which reads through the excel, creates the insert statements and executes them against the database

Comment: @EstebanP. can u please send me some reference links? where i can get to know how to proceed with the powershell thing.

Comment: @Karthik
Link for reading through Excel:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211632/read-excel-sheet-in-powershell

Link for inserts through Powershell script:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22974931/using-powershell-insert-string-values-in-sql-server-db